# How to generate a string from a genvar value in a for loop?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Xilinx requires to define different group for `IODELAY` and `IDELAY_CTRL`. I want to parameterize my instances using `generate` and `for loop`.

I need to add a different string in the Verilog attribute `(* IODELAY_GROUP = "GROUP_HERE" *)`

How can I do that? I tried a lot using MACRO, functions without any success.

```
`define makegroup(x) `"GROUP_x`"
genvar h;
for (h=0;h<=3;h=h+1) begin:myfor
  (* IODELAY_GROUP = {"GROUP_", h} *)
  (* IODELAY_GROUP = `makegroup(h) *)
  (* IODELAY_GROUP = {"GROUP_", $sformatf("%0h",h)} *)
end
```

**Edit:**

This solution `{"IODELAY_GROUP_", h + 8'h30}` doesn't work because it creates a logic bus instead of a string.

I want something that can be interpreted by the compiler not the synthesizer.

The solution does: `(* IODELAY_GROUP = 144'h3X3X3X *)` instead of `(* IODELAY_GROUP = "GROUP_X" *)`

[image: vivado]

Comment: If h is less than 8 bits (otherwise do h[7:0]), then `(* IODELAY_GROUP = {"GROUP_", h + 8'h30} *)` should work - you were almost there, just need to convert h to an ASCII character

Comment: Thanks! `h` is the genvar not a bus, how about bigger numbers? A tostring() function would have been useful..

Comment: macros are resolved **before** generate blocks processing. So, macro will not help you there. #3 (or David's answer) is your best bet.

Comment: i do not understand what you are talking about. `(*...*)`  is an attribute which gets interpreted by the tools which compile the model. Which compiler you are talking about? if you try to synthesize it, the synthesizer will do the work, if you simulate, the simulator will. I  am surprised that the synthesizer tries to create a bus for this, it should not. The values of the attributes are compile-time constant expressions.

Comment: I'm talking about Xilinx Vivado as said in the question. Concatenating with `{}` will infer a bits array/bus not a string as `"string"`. That's why I first tried with macro.